# AngularJS 1.x Chosen MultiSelect ADD New Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

I have a chosen Multi Select input using AngularJS 1.x. and i'm having a problem when i add new items to this input.

I followed this instructions of this website: [Adding new values to chosen plugin](https://boundlessjourney.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/adding-new-values-to-chosen-plugin/)

This works well, putting in case 13 (Enter) when there is no results in search:

```
    case 13:
 evt.preventDefault();
 if (this.results_showing) {
   if (!this.is_multiple || this.result_highlight) {
     return this.result_select(evt);
   }
   $(this.form_field).append('<option>' + $(evt.target).val() + '</option>');
   $(this.form_field).trigger('chosen:updated');
   this.result_highlight = this.search_results.find('li.active-result').last();
   return this.result_select(evt);
  }
  break;
```

But it works in JQUERY way, and i'm having problems to put it on the Angular Way. There is anyone who can solve this? Any ideas?

Here is a Plunk to help you guys: [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/o8A9QnzmmvIVD6matLMY?p=preview)

Thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, works like a charm

[ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/)

Here a sample

```
   <tags-input 
            replace-spaces-with-dashes='false'
            ng-model="vm.categories"
            placeholder="Add category">
        <auto-complete min-length="1" 
                     source="vm.loadMatchingTags($query)">
        </autocomplete>
   </tags-input>
```

Comment: What? haha there is nothing in your anwser :P

Comment: It is now. No jQuery at all :))

Comment: This is good, but there is no the Search plugin inside like Chosen has =/

Comment: Yes, there is, im sorry.  I will try this one! Thanks a lot haha!

Comment: I've posted a sample, the vm is the scope alias